# How to add and delete linkedserver in SQL Server in runtime using Vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I use update and insert query using joint tables in two different SQL Servers using linked server. But I don't like my remote server link open to users in SQL Server Management Studio. Instead I would like to create an delete the linked server at runtime. Is this possible using VB.net?

```
UPDATE Category 
SET Category.HQID = B.[ID], 
    Category.DepartmentID = B.[departmentid], 
    Category.Name = B.[name], 
    Category.Code = B.[code], 
    Category.LastUpdated = B.[lastupdated]
FROM 
    Category A
INNER JOIN 
    [Myremoteserver].[MyRemoteDatabase].[dbo].[Category] B ON A.HQID = B.ID
WHERE 
    A.HQID <> B.ID 
    OR A.DepartmentID <> B.departmentID 
    OR A.Name <> B.name 
    OR A.Code <> B.code 
    OR A.LastUpdated <> B.lastupdated
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do that but I would ask why. If you don't trust people with the data why do you allow them access? You could setup your link server so those people don't have access. Doing this at runtime is adding unnecessary complexity when you should be handling this with security.